# Using grep to match where two tokens occur on the same line

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, debian-based

I am reading the man page, and found [this](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm) blog post, and both seem to say the same thing, but it does not work.

I have a project where I need to batch replace lines like

```
import Foo from '/modules/foo/client/components/Foo.jsx';
```

into

```
import Foo from '/modules/foo/client/imports/Foo.jsx';
```

but I do not want to match lines like :

```
import Base from '/client/components/Base.jsx';
```

i.e. : only "imports" from the base dir `/modules`.

I have tried

```
$ grep -R "modules.+components" modules/
```

but no match is found.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you wrote that you need to *replace lines* but `grep` will only search for matches. So, what is your final goal?

Comment: I use grep all the time, but always searching one keyword at a time. I just want to make sure that I don't miss anything, as a verification tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `grep` interprets the pattern as a basic regular expression (BRE) (not extended `-E`) and treats **some** regex metacharacters literally. So `+` doesn't have special meaning in your current approach.

> Any meta-character with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it
>   with a backslash.

```
grep -R "modules.\+components" modules/
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-grep-programs

---

About ***BRE***:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#bre

Comment: @YanickRochon, good thought and yes ... it *treats some regex metacharacters literally* cause in BRE `.` also matches any character, including newline, while `+` should be escaped `\+`